# How to assign date variable value from table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, variable-assignment

The following code:

```
declare @tradeDate date = select tradeDate from tSystemStatus
```

generates error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
```

table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tSystemStatus](
    ....
    [TradeDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    ....
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: the variable defined is of type `date`. It can't hold data from multiple rows, which is what your assignment tries to do

Comment: @vkp actually there are 1 row only

Comment: then you have the answer below. use `()` around the `select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @tradeDate date = (select tradeDate from tSystemStatus)
```

But if the select query return more that one value , then it will throw error (you can use top 1 here)

```
declare @tradeDate date = (select top 1 tradeDate from tSystemStatus)
```

Or

```
declare @tradeDate date 
select @tradeDate = tradeDate from tSystemStatus
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @tradeDate date;
select @tradeDate=tradeDate from tSystemStatus
```